# Flexbox: Increase or decrease the height of the middle item proportionally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox layout:

```
<div class="flex wrap" style="
    /* height: 100%; */
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    align-content: justify-content;
">
     <div class="main" style="
    /* order: 2; */
    flex: 100%;
    background: red;
">A</div>
     <div class="optional" style="
    /* order: 1; */
    flex: 100%;
    background: black;
    /* height: 460px; */
    flex-basis: 26rem;
">B</div>
     <div class="main2" style="
    /* order: 3; */
    flex: 100%;
    background: yellow;
">C</div>
</div>
```

This is the normal state:
[image]

I want Increase or decrease the black div height, but, my flexbox grid does not do this proportionally:
[image]

I want this result, the red and yellow div adapts to black div height:
[image]

How I can get this?

Comment: May I ask what should happen with content in red/yellow if one has a lot more, should they still have the same height? ...wrap? ...always stack vertically? ....and if both have much content? ... wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `flex: 1` on both `.main` and `.main2`, and then just set `height` on `.optional`: https://jsfiddle.net/304tqrgb/

i also changed the `.flew.wrap` to not have `align-items`, since that's not needed here.